# C++ pthread Inconsistent output + Hangs

Tags: c++, multithreading

When I run the following thread application it runs successfully about 25% of the time and the rest it gets part way through and stops. It seems that if some of the threads are created after some have already started it stops the running threads... but that's just speculation. It pretty clearly manages to create all of threads and even start them all but it doesn't return from them all before it just stops. Is there some thread management I'm missing?

```
struct parameters{
    int *structArray;
    int test;
    vector<int> structVector;
};
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void* threadFunc(void* threadArg){
     pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex );
     int temp, number;
     vector<int> tempVector(10);
     struct parameters *local_data;
     local_data = (struct parameters *) threadArg;
     parameters *value = (parameters *)malloc(sizeof(parameters));
     number = local_data->test;
     cout << "In Thread Function: "<<  number<< ": ";
     for(int i = 0;i<10;i++){
         temp = local_data->structVector[i];
         cout << temp << " ";
         tempVector[i] = number * (temp);
     }
     cout << endl;
     value->structVector = tempVector;
     value->test = 1000;
     pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex );
     pthread_exit((void*)value);
}

int main(){
    int numberOfThreads = 56;
    pthread_t threads[numberOfThreads+1];
    struct parameters ThreadParameters[numberOfThreads+1];
    vector<int> mainVector(10);
    int rc;
    for(int i = 0;i<10;i++){
        mainVector[i] = i;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<numberOfThreads;i++){
        ThreadParameters[i].test = i;
        ThreadParameters[i].structVector = mainVector;
        rc = pthread_create(&threads[i],NULL,threadFunc,(void*)&ThreadParameters[i]);
    if(rc){
        cout << "Error: unable to create thread, " << rc << endl;
        return(-1);
    }
    else cout << "Thread number " << i << " created" <<  endl;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<numberOfThreads; i++){
        void *Results;
        vector<int> receivedVector(10);
        parameters answer;
        pthread_join(threads[i], &Results);
        answer = *((parameters *)Results);
        free(Results);
        receivedVector = answer.structVector;
        cout << "\nReturn from thread " << i << ": ";
        for(int j = 0; j<10;j++){
            cout << receivedVector[j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << "\n\nTest complete";
}
```

Here is an example of what it outputs:

```
Thread number 0 created
Thread number 1 created
Thread number 2 created
Thread number 3 created
Thread number 4 created
Thread number 5 created
Thread number 6 created
Thread number 7 created
Thread number 8 created
Thread number 9 created
Thread number 10 created
Thread number 11 created
Thread number 12 created
Thread number 13 created
Thread number 14 created
Thread number 15 created
Thread number 16 created
Thread number 17 created
Thread number 18 created
Thread number 19 created
Thread number 20 created
Thread number 21 created
Thread number 22 created
Thread number 23 created
Thread number 24 created
Thread number 25 created
Thread number 26 created
Thread number 27 created
Thread number 28 created
Thread number 29 created
Thread number 30 created
Thread number 31 created
Thread number 32 created
Thread number 33 created
Thread number 34 created
Thread number 35 created
Thread number 36 created
Thread number 37 created
Thread number 38 created
Thread number 39 created
Thread number 40 created
Thread number 41 created
Thread number 42 created
Thread number 43 created
Thread number 44 created
Thread number 45 created
Thread number 46 created
Thread number 47 created
Thread number 48 created
Thread number 49 created
Thread number 50 created
Thread number 51 created
Thread number 52 created
Thread number 53 created
Thread number 54 created
Thread number 55 created
In Thread Function: 5: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
In Thread Function: 7: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
In Thread Function: 10: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
In Thread Function: 12: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
In Thread Function: 52: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
In Thread Function: 20: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
In Thread Function: 24: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
In Thread Function: 26: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
In Thread Function: 29: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
In Thread Function: 37: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
In Thread Function: 43: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
In Thread Function: 45: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
In Thread Function: 22: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
In Thread Function: 14: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
In Thread Function: 41: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
In Thread Function: 18: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
In Thread Function: 27: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
In Thread Function: 33: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
In Thread Function: 39: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
In Thread Function: 47: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
In Thread Function: 48: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
In Thread Function: 50: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
In Thread Function: 54: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
In Thread Function: 16: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
In Thread Function: 35: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
In Thread Function: 3: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
In Thread Function: 2: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
In Thread Function: 1: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
In Thread Function: 0: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 

Return from thread 0: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 

Return from thread 1: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 

Return from thread 2: 0 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 

Return from thread 3: 0 3 6 9 12 15 18 21 24 27 
In Thread Function: 51: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
In Thread Function: 55: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
In Thread Function: 19: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
In Thread Function: 23: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
In Thread Function: 25: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
In Thread Function: 28: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
In Thread Function: 36: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
In Thread Function: 42: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
In Thread Function: 44: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
In Thread Function: 21: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
In Thread Function: 13: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
In Thread Function: 40: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
In Thread Function: 4: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
In Thread Function: 6: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 

Return from thread 4: 0 4 8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36 

Return from thread 5: 0 5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 

Return from thread 6: 0 6 12 18 24 30 36 42 48 54 

Return from thread 7: 0 7 14 21 28 35 42 49 56 63 
In Thread Function: 8: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 

Return from thread 8: 0 8 16 24 32 40 48 56 64 72 

Return from thread 9: 0 9 18 27 36 45 54 63 72 81 

Return from thread 10: 0 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 
In Thread Function: 11: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 

Return from thread 11: 0 11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 99 

Return from thread 12: 0 12 24 36 48 60 72 84 96 108 

Return from thread 13: 0 13 26 39 52 65 78 91 104 117 

Return from thread 14: 0 14 28 42 56 70 84 98 112 126 
In Thread Function: 17: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
In Thread Function: 30: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
In Thread Function: 31: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
In Thread Function: 32: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
In Thread Function: 38: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
In Thread Function: 46: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: I don't know how this runs at all. `mutex` is a dreadful name for a global, as it is also the name of a `std` class, and you've clearly sucked in the standard namespace with a `using namespace std;` statement somewhere. Second, this uses VLA's a C99 feature proffered by non-standard extension only in some C++ toolchains like gcc. Third, a VLA of a non-POD type is *not* good and in most cases, not even *allowed*. You should include your toolchain info in your question, as it is clearly important if anyone wants to try to compile this.

Comment: By "stops", do you mean crashes? Or hangs?

Comment: This: `parameters *value = (parameters *)malloc(sizeof(parameters));` is a terrible idea. You're raw-mallocing a non-POD type that contains a `std::vector<>` member. The internal vector is never actually constructed, and internally contains indeterminate garbage. That should be `new`-ed, and `delete`-ed back in `main()`, and frankly I see no reason for it in the first place.

Comment: Use a debugger to see where it "stops". And as it was said already, malloc() for that structure is terrible - you never call constructor of that vector and it is left in undetermined state that then you use later. Then the free() leaks that vector's memory everywhere as the destructor is never called.